# For the command pm.plot_posterior of pymc3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, arviz

Usually, I find we use the `pm.binomial()` and so forth. and using the pm.plot_posterior we get the Discrete graph, my question is why my graph I have to get is a curve? Could someone enlighten me?

I want to get:

[image]

But I get the graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kind` argument accepts either `"kde"` (default for continuous) or `"hist"`.

```python
import arviz as az

az.plot_posterior(trace, kind="hist")
```

Please see [the documentation](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/api/generated/arviz.plot_posterior.html).

Comment: Note that `pm.<plot_function>` will no longer work starting with pymc3>=3.11 (released on Jan 21st 2021), the aliases to ArviZ functions have been removed and ArviZ has to be called directly. Here are the release notes: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES.md#pymc3-3110-21-january-2021